# SSIS - Dynamic source and destination tables

Tags: ssis

I have 30+ tables from which I need to import data. I can create dataflow components and do the same, but then I would need to create source/destination/checking record count for all 30+ tables.

How can I, while using one component (and iterating through it) or using a script component, create dynamic code that takes source and destination connection parameters and then imports the data?

I am looking to create a package which iterates through table names and then creates appropriate mappings and imports the data.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763072/using-dynamically-named-table-in-ssis-data-flow-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1Create a one mapping table for source and target table
2create script task and use bulkcopy function to mapped the source and target columns
3run the bulkcopy function

Comment: But here, If CSV is source and SQL is destination, data type mismatch may occur rite, how to handle those